# What is this Excel formula supposed to do?

Tags: excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet in which I'm supposed to fix up broken formulas. Does anyone know what this is 'meant' to do?

```
=#REF!A33
```

Answer (score 7):

That means there was a reference to a worksheet or a named range that has been deleted.

In other words it may have been

```
=Worksheet2!A33
```

but Worksheet2 has been deleted.

Possibly nearby cells have similar formulas that still point to a valid location and you can recreate what it pointed to...

Answer (score 1):

Invalid cell reference errors occur when a spreadsheet formula contains incorrect cell references.

See: http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/formulatips/qt/REF_error.htm

Answer (score 1):

It probably was referencing a cell on another sheet which got deleted

so

```
 =Sheet1!A33
```

becomes

```
 =#REF!A33
```